# how can I show yearly chart on buttonclick in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

By default I show a chart for monthly data in my view using chartkick and highcharts. i have already prepared a hash for showing yearly chart but how can I show show yearly chart on buttonclick. My html:

```
<div class="flot-chart">
  <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flot-dashboard-chart">
    <%= column_chart @chart_by_month ,height: "200px",width: "900px" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the button I have added is only month. I will add a chart for yearly data, but how do I show it with button click?

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" id="by_month" class="btn btn-xs btn-white">Monthly</button>                                           
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you need to implement the ajax call described in section [Say goodbye to timeouts](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#say-goodbye-to-timeouts) and then add the filter you want in the controller and also js functionality. Do not forget the route.

Some like:

HTML:

```
<div class="flot-chart">
   <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flot-dashboard-chart">
    <%= column_chart chart_by_period_path( period: "month") ,height: "200px",width: "900px" , id: "id_g1" %>
   </div>
</div>
```

ROUTE:

```
...
get 'chart_by_period/(:period)', to: "controller#chart_by_period", as: "chart_by_period"
...
```

JS:

```
...
var g1     = Chartkick.charts["id_g1"];

$("button#refresh_graph__year_btn").on('click', function(){
    g1.updateData( "/chart_by_period/year");
});
...
```

CONTROLLER:

```
def chart_by_period
    if params[:period] == "month"
        ...
        output = ....
        ...
    elsif params[:period] == "year" 
        ...
        output = ....
        ...
    end

    render json: output
end
```

Comment: I do not know, maybe yo can see the documentacion or the code of the gem. Why you do not want json?

Comment: i have used ajax. and if it could be done with javascript?

Comment: I do not see the problem of use json because you do not have to touch the data, the gem do all, you only have to do the query and ruby/rails make the convertion of ActiveRecord, array or hash to json with `render json: output` . Read the section [Data](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#data) seems to accept array and hash

Comment: Thank you so much.. and yes , you're absolutely right about json. But I haven't used json in my application. That's why.